# Can coffeescript output sourcemap during node runtime execution (not pre-compiled)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, source-maps

We have a Node.JS web app that is written in CoffeeScript that we run/execute using the coffee command (e.g. `coffee app.coffee`) vs precompiling to js first (e.g. `coffee -m -c app.coffee` then `node app.js`). I know when compiling CoffeeScript you can pass the `-m` flag to generate a source map file...can/does CoffeeScript generate source map files on runtime execution?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet (July 2014), but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3187) for this on GitHub.